# Laravel Image base64 encode conversion

Tags: laravel

I used this code to insert an encoded image file in the database using laravel.

Here is my code

```
if ($request->has('news_image')) {
    $file = $request->file('news_image');
    $filename = time() . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $filepath = public_path('/NewsImages/');
    $file->move($filepath, $filename);

    $n->news_image = base64_encode('/NewsImages/' . $filename);
}
```

It gives me :  `L05ld3NJbWFnZXMvMTU5MTQ3MDc1MC5qcGc=`

Is it okay?

Though I haven't check it yet by decryption.

Comment: What you did was only encode a path to image. Feel free to save path without any encoding.

Comment: What is it you're wanting to achieve? Is the code you have causing an issue/error?

Comment: I am wanting to insert image, it worked, but in controller when i used $image = base64_decode($fetch->news_image); echo $image; this worked... but when I used <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{$fetch->news_image}}" width="100" height="50" alt="base64 test"> in the blade file, its showing corrupted image

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are not encoding the image currently, you gave the function the path to the image, to encode the image you can update your code like this:

```php
$n->news_image = base64_encode(file_get_contents('/NewsImages/' . $filename));
```

After that to decode your image you retrieve your model from the database and simply run `base64_decode()` on the `news_image` field.

```php
$image = base64_decode($model->news_image);

echo $image; // To show the image to the browser
```

Comment: Thanks to suggest, But, $n->news_image = base64_encode('/NewsImages/' . $filename); works for me

Comment: $image = base64_decode($model->news_image);

echo $image; thanks for this suggestion, it worked. thanks a lot

Comment: but when I used <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{$fetch->news_image}}" width="100" height="50" alt="base64 test"> in the blade file, its showing corrupted image

Comment: $n->news_image = base64_encode(file_get_contents('/NewsImages/' . $filename)); somehow, i dont know, it didn't work for me...